# Google Charts Trailing Zero

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a google chart that I am using 
https://developers.google.com/chart/

but can't seem to get the tooltip to display trailing zeros!

I tried formatting the data as in #.# but if there is an even number it doesn't display the decimal!

Ie my data is:77.6,77.1,77.0,66.9
in the tooltip though the  77.0 shows as 77

I would want to show 77.0 in the tooltip.

I confirmed that the data is coming in as 77.0, so google must be parsing it out.

I don't want to use a custom annotation either, because I like the way the stock tooltip looks.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

to display trailing zeroes, the format must include `0` instead `#` (which hides zeroes)

```
'#,##0.00'
```

the tooltip will display the formatted value by default,
format the column to change the tooltip

```
var formatNumber = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
  pattern: '#,##0.00'
});
formatNumber.format(data, 1);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawTable,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawTable() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y');
  data.addRows([
    [0, 77.0],
    [1, 77.1],
    [2, 77.2],
    [3, 77.3],
    [4, 77.4],
    [5, 77.5]
  ]);

  var formatNumber = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: '#,##0.00'
  });
  formatNumber.format(data, 1);

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data, {
    pointSize: 8
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

---

**UPDATE**

a number is just a number, it has no format
passing `77` vs. `77.0` makes no difference to the google data table

as mentioned above, the tooltip will display the formatted value of the cell value

each cell in the data table has a value property (`v:`) and formatted value property (`f:`)

when loading the data, you can pass just the value...

```
data.addRows([
  [0, 77.0],
  ...
]);
```

or you can use object notation, to pass both value and formatted value,
here a number formatter *would not* be needed

```
data.addRows([
  [0, {v: 77.0, f: '77.0'}],
  ...
]);
```

however, when passing just the value,
the data table uses a default format to show on the tooltip
this default format does not match what you want
which is why you must use a number formatter,
which sets the formatted value for all rows in the column

**note:** the following options *only affect the axis labels*, not the tooltip...

```
vAxis.format
hAxis.format
```

Comment: is there a reason you have to manululate the data itself? I confirmed the data is coming across as 77.0

When I try to pass the option "format":"##0.0" it still shows 77.0 as 77